# magento flat table adding columns of final price, percentage discount

Tags: magento, indexing, flat

Objective : Want to display listing sort by percentage discount.

Step 1: In indexer when flat table is being populated add a two columns one of final price and second of percentage discount.

Query : How should this be achieved?
Should some class be extended or should I use some observer or is there any extension that will do this.

Appreciate architectural guide line or code snippets.

Comment: Additional info is that flat table final price should consider catalog price rules as well

Comment: My above question is related to enterprise version.What has been observed is that catalog rule price indexing is not consistent.I want to add an observer on some event that is fired whenever catalog product price indexing occurs(individual product or in bulk update)instead of flat table if I can populate catalog product price index table that too is ok.